# Flutter web pixeloverflow handling all screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want my flutter web app to scroll instead of overflowing, it can be horizontal or vertical.
There is not much writings on how to handle responsiveness in flutter web. Should I give widgets exact height and width or should it be like size.width/2 ?

And is there any way for scrolling the whole page instead of overflowing pixels?

Comment: Could you please share any UI image or code associated with your issue?

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1):

For a given direction (either horizontal or vertical), the easiest way is to use a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Row` or `Column` as its child respectively.

For vertical:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: Column(...),
);
```

For horizontal:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(...),
);
```

You could then use widgets with size relative  to the other axis to make it scale in that way. Without knowing your app or layout, it's difficult to know what would work, but here are some ideas (in no particular order):

1. You can use `FractionallySizedBox`es to make some Widgets fill up a given fraction of the space on the screen (both horizontal and vertical): https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html
2. You can use the `Flexible` Widget to give some Widgets a relative size using their `flexFactor`s, and size some widgets proportionally. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html
3. In the cross-axis direction for a `Row`/`Column`, you can have some sized Widgets, and use an `Expanded` widget to fill up the remaining space. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Just play around with all the mentioned information, and see what works for your app!